# How to make a generic extension method in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli, extension-methods

I have checked, this works (I can call the extension method from a C# program):

```
[ExtensionAttribute]
public ref class ArrayExtensions abstract sealed {
public:        
    [ExtensionAttribute]
    static array<int>^ FlipExt(array<int> ^ vals)
    {
        int n = vals->Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
        {
            int tmp = vals[i];
            vals[i] = vals[n - i - 1];
            vals[n - i - 1] = tmp;
        }
        return vals;
    }
};
```

This also works (I can call the generic method from a C# program):

```
public ref class ArrayUtils abstract sealed {
public:        

    generic <typename T>
    static array<T>^ FlipGen(array<T> ^ vals)
    {
        int n = vals->Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
        {
            T tmp = vals[i];
            vals[i] = vals[n - i - 1];
            vals[n - i - 1] = tmp;
        }
        return vals;
    }
};
```

This C# code also works, so generic extension methods are supported by .NET:

```
public static class ArrayExtensionsSharp
{
    public static T[] FlipExtSharp<T>(this T[] vals)
    {
        int n = vals.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
        {
            var tmp = vals[i];
            vals[i] = vals[n - i - 1];
            vals[n - i - 1] = tmp;
        }
        return vals;
    }
}
```

But when I do this, it says "error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'"

```
[ExtensionAttribute]
public ref class ArrayExtensions abstract sealed {
public:        
    [ExtensionAttribute]
    generic <typename T>
    static array<T>^ FlipGenExt(array<T> ^ vals)
    {
        int n = vals->Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
        {
            T tmp = vals[i];
            vals[i] = vals[n - i - 1];
            vals[n - i - 1] = tmp;
        }
        return vals;
    }
};
```

So, what's up? Is there a way to make a generic extension method in C++/CLI?

I want to do it in C++/CLI because the actual extension method I need is closely related to a C++/CLI method and I wan't them both in the same assembly.
Thanks.

edit:
Note that the answer below works, but the MSDN documentation seems (to me) to indicate otherwise:

generic class definition (from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skef48fy.aspx))

```
[attributes]
generic <class-key type-parameter-identifier(s)>
[constraint-clauses]
[accessibility-modifiers] ref class identifier  [modifiers]
[: base-list] 
{ 
class-body 
} [declarators] [;]
```

generic function definition (from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssea4yk6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

```
[attributes] [modifiers]
return-type identifier <type-parameter identifier(s)>
[type-parameter-constraints clauses]

([formal-parameters])
{
   function-body
}
```

It looks like the generic function specification is for C#, not C__ (no "generic" keyword,  comes right after the function name.)  But it is on the C++ page, I guess I looked at the class specification, which has attributes before the word generic, but this is wrong too.  Are the Microsoft docs just totally wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the placement of the attribute:

```
 generic <typename T>
 [ExtensionAttribute]
 static array<T>^ FlipGenExt(array<T> ^ vals)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; that worked.  I added to the question because I wasn't sure if I could get the code sample into the comment, but it looks like the Microsoft Docs are wrong on this, or am I reading it wrong or looking in the wrong place?